# Append Enum Flags to a Parameter in a Loop (Bitwise Appending)

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, enum-flags

In C#, I am trying to "add" values to a parameter that accepts enumerated flags.  I can do it on one line with a bitwise operator "|", but I can't seem append to the parameter in a loop.

I have the following Enum specified as Flags.

```
[Flags]
public enum ProtectionOptions
{
  NoPrevention = 0,
  PreventEverything = 1,
  PreventCopying = 2,
  PreventPrinting = 4,
  PrintOnlyLowResolution = 8
}
```

Now, I can easily use the following code to add flag values to the parameter:

```
myObj.Protection = ProtectionOptions.PreventEverything | ProtectionOptions.PrintOnlyLowResolution;
```

But, what I want to do, is to get a list of protection options from a CSV string (from the Web.Config), loop through them and add them to my myObj.ProtectionOptions property.  I don't know how to do this in a loop without using the bitwise OR "|" operator.  Here is what I am wanting to do:

```
string protectionOptionsString = "NoPrevention, PreventPrinting";
string[] protectionOptions = protectionOptionsString.Split(',');
foreach (string protectionOption in protectionOptions)
{
  myObj.Protection += (ProtectionOptions) Enum.Parse(typeof (ProtectionOptions), protectionOption.Trim());
}
```

Conceptually, this is what I want, but I can't "+=" the values in the loop to the parameter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to split. Enum.Parse is capable of parsing multiple values if you use the [Flags] attribute on the enum definition, which you did. Just parse and use the |= operator to "add" the flags.

```
string protectionOptionsString = "NoPrevention, PreventPrinting";
myObj.Protection |= (ProtectionOptions)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProtectionOptions), protectionOptionsString);
```

Comment: Perfect... that worked.  Thanks!  Two quick questions for you.  One, out of curiosity, if I wanted "append" flags without using the built in Parse function, it it possible?  Two, for my Enum, I have heard conflicting stories on whether I should use a 0 value and give it a name.  If I do use the 0 value, should it be "None" or can it be anything?

Comment: If the value is represented as a string you have to use Parse to convert to an instance of the enum. 
You should not use 0 unless it is None. The problem is that if programmers who use your enum check for the value they sometimes use 0 for comparison (which they shouldn't, but it's common). If 0 is a value rather than lack of value, then if ((currentWeather & Cloudy) != 0) to test whether the flag has Cloudy when Cloudy is defined as 0 will return false instead of the expected true. I mention that in much detail in my tutorial. Follow the link I specified in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `|=` operator.

```
myObj.Protection |= (ProtectionOptions) Enum.Parse(typeof (ProtectionOptions), protectionOption.Trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do this?

```
string protectionOptionsString = "NoPrevention, PreventPrinting";
string[] protectionOptions = protectionOptionsString.Split(',');
foreach (string protectionOption in protectionOptions)
{
  myObj.Protection |= (ProtectionOptions) Enum.Parse(typeof (ProtectionOptions), protectionOption.Trim());
}
```

Alternatively, you could store the integer equivalent of the enumeration `((Int32)myObj.Protection)` and load it as an integer as well.

Comment: Thanks Zelda, that answers my first question posted to Motti.  I accepted his answer as it's cleaner for my needs right now, but that clears up that I need to use a "|=" instead of "+=" to append.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [compound OR assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
string protectionOptionsString = "NoPrevention, PreventPrinting";
string[] protectionOptions = protectionOptionsString.Split(',');

foreach (string protectionOption in protectionOptions)
{
  myObj.Protection |= (ProtectionOptions)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProtectionOptions), 
                                                    protectionOption.Trim());
}
```